# Python: Running multiple http requests concurrently based on an initial request?

Tags: python, apache, http, nginx, concurrency

Currently I am trying to fetch from an API which has 2 endpoints:

```
GET /AllUsers 
GET /user_detail/{id}
```

In order to get the details of all the users, I would have to call `GET /AllUsers`, and loop through the IDs to call the `GET /user_detail/{id}` endpoint 1 by 1. I wonder if it's possible to have multiple `GET /user_detail/{id}` calls running at the same time? Or perhaps there is a better approach?

Comment: You could use threading as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: It seems like the structure depends greatly upon what you wish to do with each ID that you retrieve. What happens to each user once they are retrieved?

Comment: @JacobIRR: I am trying to sync those data with my local DB, so for each user I would check if the data is changed and then update my local DB accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great use case for [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

```
import grequests

urls = [f'http://example.com/user_detail/{id}' for id in range(10)]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(rs)
```

**Edit**: As an example for processing responses to retrieve json you could:

```
data = []
for response in responses:
    data.append(response.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, however the documentation doesn't specify how to process the response from each requests, is that possible with grequests?

Comment: What do you intend to do with each response? `grequests.map(rs)` returns a list of the responses